# Add watch in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add $watch in my directive. The directive is for wizard creation , when I read an existing array and use ng-repeat in directive it works as expected but If I update my array the newly added items in array doesn't add in directive to create wizard.

Please refer [This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tUEbz1JxvHuGe4Xij0Eu?p=preview) to understand the issue. At this plunker script.js has array data which I will be updating on a button click and read them back in ng-repeat under wizard directive on html page.

the directive is

```
  directive('wizard', function($timeout, $compile) { 
      var opts = {
                headerTag: "h3",
                bodyTag: "section",
                transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
                autoFocus: true,
                enableAllSteps: true,
                enableKeyNavigation: false,
                enableCancelButton: true,
                enableFinishButton: true,
                showFinishButtonAlways: false
              };


              return {
                restrict: 'E', 
                replace: true,
                template: '<div class="mywizard"></div>', 
                compile: function (tEl) {
                  return function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    var stepsEl;
                    element.wrapInner('<div class="steps-wrapper">');
                    element.children('.steps-wrapper').append(tEl.context.innerHTML);
                    var content = $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                    $timeout(function () {
                      element.children('.steps-wrapper').steps(opts);
                    })
                  }
                }

              };
            });
```

Please share idea where should I apply the watch.

Comment: I did not get so much time to look at the plunkr completely but your watch goes well with your controller. Thats where it needs to be. But I believe to propagate value from outside directive you will be better off by using the data captured and changed in services.

Comment: First thing you should be interested in - if this 'jquery steps' supports adding new elements directly to DOM. Otherwise I doubt you can get all this working easily. I mean you can easily add watch - but what next? Say array changed - you are going to reinit all directive? ...

Comment: I want to add steps when array changes,but not sure why its not working